# De-duplicating elements of dictionary based on conditions [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, data-science

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
dict = {
'key-1': [('blue', '-20'), ('red', '-67')], 
'key-2': [('blue', '-77'), ('cyan', '-67'), ('white', '-57')],
'key-3': [('blue', '-39'), ('cyan , '-35'), ('purple', '-60')]
}
```

The above dictionary contains keys with tuples("color", "weights"). I want to filter the list such that if a color is duplicated in the dictionary then the tuple with the highest weight should be kept and all other occurances of that color should be popped out of the dictionary.

In this case the filtered dictionary should look like this :

```
filtered_dict = {
'key-1': [('blue', '-20'), ('red', '-67')], 
'key-2': [('white', '-57')],
'key-3': [('purple', '-60'), ('cyan', '-35')]
}
```

The dictionary is generated dynamically with colors and weights. How should i approach this problem ?

If necessary the structure in which the dictionary is formed can be changed.

[Edit: The weights are negative numbers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a dictionary with all the max weights for each color using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

dic = {
    'key-1': [('blue', '-20'), ('red', '-67')], 
    'key-2': [('blue', '-77'), ('cyan', '-67'), ('white', '-57')],
    'key-3': [('blue', '-39'), ('cyan' , '-35'), ('purple', '-60')]
}

color_weight_groups = defaultdict(list)

for lst in dic.values():
    for color, weight in lst:
        color_weight_groups[color].append(weight)

max_weights = {k: max(map(int, v)) for k, v in color_weight_groups.items()}

print(max_weights)
```

Which will look like this:

```
{'blue': -20, 'red': -67, 'cyan': -35, 'white': -57, 'purple': -60}
```

Then create a new dictionary that compares each weight against the max weight:

```
result = {
    k: [(color, weight) for color, weight in v if int(weight) == max_weights[color]]
    for k, v in dic.items()
}

print(result)
```

Which gives this filtered result:

```
{'key-1': [('blue', '-20'), ('red', '-67')], 'key-2': [('white', '-57')], 'key-3': [('cyan', '-35'), ('purple', '-60')]}
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a max_dict that holds all the color-max key-value pairs. Then iterate through the original dictionary, comparing each tuple to the max_dict.

```
key_dict = {
'key-1': [('blue', '20'), ('red', '67')], 
'key-2': [('blue', '77'), ('cyan', '67'), ('white', '57')],
'key-3': [('blue', '39'), ('cyan' , '35'), ('purple', '60')]
}

# create a max_dict including all the key-value pairs of color-maximum value
max_dict = dict()

for color_list in key_dict.values():
    for item in color_list:
        if item[0] not in max_dict.keys():
            max_dict.update({item[0]: int(item[1])})
        else:
            if int(item[1]) > max_dict[item[0]]:
                max_dict.update({item[0]: int(item[1])})

# create a list to hold all the updated list of tuples from the original dictionary
list_of_values = []

# sort through the original dictionary, comparing each tuple to the max_dict key-value pairs
for color_list in key_dict.values():
    list_of_tuples = []
    for item in color_list:
        if int(item[1]) == max_dict[item[0]]:
            list_of_tuples.append(item)
    list_of_values.append(list_of_tuples)

filtered_dict = dict(zip(key_dict.keys(), list_of_values))
```

Output:

```
>>> filtered_dict
{'key-1': [('red', '67')], 'key-2': [('blue', '77'), ('cyan', '67'), ('white', '57')], 'key-3': [('purple', '60')]}
```